# I need to print the series in Java

Tags: java, arrays

I would like to print the following series in Java as 9,17,26,38,52......
In this first is Fibonacci series and other is square of a number
(0+3*3),(1+4*4),(1+5*5),(2+6*6),(3+7*7)

```
Class Program

{

int n1,n2,n3,n4;

public static void main(String args[])

{

for(int i=2;i < count; i++)

n3 =  n1 + n2;

for(int a=3; a < count;a++)

n4=  n3 + Math.(a,2);

System.out.println(""+n4);

n1=n2;

n2=n3;
}
```

Comment: That won't compile. Please post real code, please tell us in detail what problems your code is having.

Comment: I know that,that's why I asked.

Comment: @AbhishekDalakoti have a look now to the answer

Answer (score 0):

Your solution seems way too complex to me. Your question implies that item at position i = fib(i) + sqr(i + 4). If that's the case then it's best if you just code it explicitly like that:

```
class WeirdSequence {
    private int current = 1;
    private int previous = 0;
    private int count = 0;
    public int current() {
        return current + (count + 4) * (count + 4);
    }
    public void next() {
        int next = current + previous;
        previous = current;
        current = next;
        count++;
    }
}
```

You can then generate as many of these as you want:

```
WeirdSequence sequence = new WeirdSequence();
System.out.println(sequence.current());
sequence.next();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Example {
    static void Fibonacci(int N)
    {
        int num1 = 0, num2 = 1;
        int counter = 0;

        while (counter < N) 
        {
            for(int i=3; i<10 ;i++)
            {
                int y = num1+i*i;
                System.out.print(y+ " ");
  
                int num3 = num2 + num1;
                num1 = num2;
                num2 = num3;
                counter = counter + 1;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int N = 10;
  
        Fibonacci(N);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).